# OpenMP Task Scheduling Policies

Tags: parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks, task, openmp

I would like to know how the task scheduling of the OpenMP task queue is performed.

[Here](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/888/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-540-79561-2_9.pdf?auth66=1400680835_d03651d20d945141974d79deee6ed30a&ext=.pdf) I read that, by default, OpenMP imposes a breadth-first scheduler and that they did some tests FIFO vs. LIFO, but they don't say anything about the default. Since I only have a single thread (I use the single directive) creating multiple tasks, I don't think it makes any sense comparing their breadth-first vs work-first scheduling.

So, is the default FIFO or LIFO? And is it possible to change it?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note I didn't put in the answer: in the article you link they say `OpenMP...does not specify how the scheduling of these tasks should be done (although it imposes some restrictions)`. I think you may have misinterpreted some statement when you say `OpenMP imposes a breadth-first scheduler`...

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know how the task scheduling of the OpenMP task queue is performed

## Abstract version

Task scheduling in OpenMP is implementation defined, even though the [standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) imposes some restrictions on the algorithm. Should you need to manipulate the scheduler, the place to search is the particular OpenMP implementation you are targeting.

## The long tale

The basic concept upon which all the task scheduling machinery is defined is that of *task scheduling point* (see section 2.11.3):

> Whenever a thread reaches a task scheduling point, the implementation
>   may cause it to perform a task switch, beginning or resuming execution
>   of a different task bound to the current team.

In the notes below they give a broader explanation of what should be the expected behavior (emphasis mine):

> Task scheduling points dynamically **divide task regions into parts**.
>   Each part is executed uninterrupted from start to end. Different parts
>   of the same task region are executed in the order in which they are
>   encountered. In the absence of task synchronization constructs, the
>   order in which a thread executes parts of different schedulable tasks
>   is unspecified.
>
> A correct program must behave correctly and consistently with all
>   conceivable scheduling sequences that are compatible with the rules
>   above
>   ...

The standard also specifies **where** task scheduling points are implied:

> - the point immediately following the generation of an explicit task
> - after the point of completion of a task region
> - in a taskyield region
> - in a taskwait region
> - at the end of a taskgroup region
> - in an implicit and explicit barrier region
> - the point immediately following the generation of a target region
> - at the beginning and end of a target data region
> - in a target update region

and **what** a thread may do when it meets one of them:

> - begin execution of a tied task bound to the current team
> - resume any suspended task region, bound to the current team, to which it is tied
> - begin execution of an untied task bound to the current team
> - resume any suspended untied task region bound to the current team.

It says explicitly, though:

> If more than one of the above choices is available, it is unspecified
>   as to which will be chosen.

leaving space for different conforming behaviors. It only imposes four constraints:

> 1. An included task is executed immediately after generation of the task.
> 2. Scheduling of new tied tasks is constrained by the set of task regions that are currently tied to the thread, and that are not
>      suspended in a barrier region. If this set is empty, any new tied task
>      may be scheduled. Otherwise, a new tied task may be scheduled only if
>      it is a descendent task of every task in the set.
> 3. A dependent task shall not be scheduled until its task dependences are fulfilled.
> 4. When an explicit task is generated by a construct containing an if clause for which the expression evaluated to false, and the previous
>      constraints are already met, the task is executed immediately after
>      generation of the task.

that every scheduling algorithm must fulfill to be considered conforming.

Comment: What about the tasks that are waiting in the queue to get executed? In which order is the task queue accessed? Is there no information about this?

Comment: @fc67 Apart from the four constraints, everything else is peculiar to the specific implementation.